# how to change the css height?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want the height of the upper right cell to be 75% of the total.  I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

Here is the html that creates it:

```
<div id="grid4" class="grid">
    <div class="innerGrid" >
        <div class="gridColumn" gs-width="20%">
            <div class="gridCell">
                <div class="fillCell"><a> Watchlist </a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridCell">
                <div class="fillCell"><a> Notes </a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gridColumn" gs-width="80%">
            <div class="gridCell">
                 <div class="gridColumn">
                      <div class="gridCell">
                          <div class="fillCell"><a> Candlestick Chart </a></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridCell">
                <div class="fillCell"><a> Volume Bar Chart </a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The dividers are jquery splitters that you can drag to change the size. They apparently change the html to include the class descriptors they need.

If I look at the elements section and highlight the element, I see this:

[image]

So I put the following in my css:

```
div#grid4-101599944959854.gridCell.isResizable.hasChildren.hasContent {
    height: 75%;
}
```

But it has no effect.

If I look at the right side of the Elements page I see this:

```
element.style {
    border: 0px;
    height: 50.0668%;
}
```

If I force the height to 75%, then it does what I want.  But of course if I refresh the page, it goes back to the way it was.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the height it's been set inline straight in to the element by the jQuery plugin. I'm not sure if it's the cleanest solution but you could try to override the CSS by doing:

```
.gridCell.hasChildren {
    height: 75% !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked.  But why does it need the !important?  I've heard that is bad programming practice.

Comment: by using !important you can override all other CSS styles, it is not a good practice but it can be of a help in some situations. Please can you upvote my answer if it was of a help for you?

Comment: sure will and thank you!  I will check it as the solution if I don't get an answer that doesn't use !important.